# Why does this dictionary suddenly become empty?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file "country.csv" that looks precisely like this:

```
Country Code,Country Name,Country-ID
US,United States,0
DE,Germany,1
AU,Australia,2
CZ,Czechia,3
CA,Canada,4
AR,Argentina,5
BR,Brazil,6
PT,Portugal,7
GB,United Kingdom,8
IT,Italy,9
GG,Guernsey,10
RO,Romania,11
ES,Spain,12
FR,France,13
NL,Netherlands,14
,,15
SK,Slovakia,16
```

I wrote a simple Python script that, using dictionaries, reads this file into "country_dictionary" and prints the "lines" out. However, after running through "country_dictionary" once it suddenly becomes empty. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
import csv

def csv_to_dictionary(csv_name, delimiter):
    input_file = csv.DictReader(open(csv_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8'), delimiter=delimiter)
    return input_file

country_dictionary = csv_to_dictionary("country.csv", ',')
country_list = []
for row in country_dictionary:
    print(row)
    country_list.append(row["Country Code"])
print(country_list)                                   #Up to here everything works as intended

for row in country_dictionary:
    print(row)                        # The dictionary seems to be empty?
```

Comment: DictReader object can be read once.
Try to change the return function on `csv_to_dictionary` to `return [ row for row in input_file ]`

Comment: You simply need to be aware of the nature of `csv.DictReader`. In the documentation: `Create an object that operates like a regular reader but maps the information in each row to a dict whose keys are given by the optional fieldnames parameter`. 
If it is a reader, then if you iterate through it and you reach the end, you will have to open the file again. 
So depending on your case, if you want to lazy read every time and not keep the content in memory for second reads or store in memory for later use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script reads through the file so there is nothing else to read at the second `for` loop. If you want to read through again add `country_dictionary = csv_to_dictionary("country.csv", ',')` before the loop again

Or as @Pujianto mentions, have `csv_to_dictionary` return a copy of `input_file` with `return [ row for row in input_file ]`